# iOS UIWebView not accepting URL changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a strange problem with my UIWebView, it is not accepting any changes.

When I start the app it loads the URL perfectly, delegate methods are being fired as should, BUT the UIWebView is not accepting any actions after that, like hiding it, or changing it's URL. When I call `[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];` to change the current URL to another one, delegate methods are being fired but the WebView keeps viewing the OLD page, no change (only indicator shows for few seconds and then the log commands in `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` and `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` works fine).

Here is the scenario below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");

    NSString *urlString = @"http://old.example.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

    // For here, everything is fine, the WebView loads the OLD URL

    webView.delegate = self;
    webView.opaque = NO;
    webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 100.0, 40.0);
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(loadNotificationUrl:)
                                                 name:@"loadNotificationUrl" object:nil];

}

-(void)loadNotificationUrl:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    // Now the notification arrives holding the NEW URL
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSString* NotificationUrl = (NSString*)userInfo[@"url"];
    NSLog (@"Successfully received: %@", NotificationUrl); // it gets --> "http://new.example.com"

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:NotificationUrl];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"Before Load: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"]); // --> this is showing "about:blank"!!

    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest]; // This works but doesn't change anything in the WebView! OLD page still showing.


}
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial request is loaded in a different web view than the future ones. If you look in your code you have `[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];`

And then a few lines down you have `webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];` which sets the `webView` variable to a new UIWebView instance, which you then add to your view. This web view isn't visible though because it's frame is presumably `CGRectZero`. The delegate methods are firing because you've set the new instance's delegate as self, but again you can't see the result.

Remove the `webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];` and things may behave as you expect, assuming you've initialized the web view elsewhere.

Comment: You made my day man, thank you!
what was this for? `webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];`

Answer (score 1):

after  *loadRequest:urlRequest*,you have create a new UIWebView,which override the old webView,please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
```

before this line:

```
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

in this method:

```
viewDidLoad
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the webView = [UIWebView alloc]init]; should work